# Prepend, copy/paste, and append using sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file full of IDs which I need to use to build a list of URLs as part of a bash file.

`ids.txt` is as follows:

```
    s_Foo
    p_Bar
    s1_Blah
    e_Yah
```

The URLs will always end in a filename that contains the ID, in its own path.

I've looked around for how to prepend and append using `sed`, but cannot figure out to do the duplicating copy/paste part (\1) using that tool. The ID can be anything, so pattern matching seems hard. Duplication of everything before the line break seems more sensible? I don't know.

How do I create something like this as `urls.txt` using `sed` or `awk`? Is it possible?

```
    https://link.domain.com/list/s_Foo/s_Foo_meta.xml
    https://link.domain.com/list/p_Bar/p_Bar_meta.xml
    https://link.domain.com/list/s1_Blah/s1_Blah_meta.xml
    https://link.domain.com/list/e_Yah/e_Yah_meta.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sed 's#.*#https://link.domain.com/list/&/&_meta.xml#' ids.txt
https://link.domain.com/list/s_Foo/s_Foo_meta.xml
https://link.domain.com/list/p_Bar/p_Bar_meta.xml
https://link.domain.com/list/s1_Blah/s1_Blah_meta.xml
https://link.domain.com/list/e_Yah/e_Yah_meta.xml

$ awk '{sub(/.*/,"https://link.domain.com/list/&/&_meta.xml")}1' ids.txt
https://link.domain.com/list/s_Foo/s_Foo_meta.xml
https://link.domain.com/list/p_Bar/p_Bar_meta.xml
https://link.domain.com/list/s1_Blah/s1_Blah_meta.xml
https://link.domain.com/list/e_Yah/e_Yah_meta.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

try gnu sed:

```
sed -E 's/\S+/https://link.domain.com/list/&/&_meta.xml' ids.txt >urls.txt
```